# How to use XGBoost softprob multi class classification such that I do not get the error for num_class?

Tags: python, xgboost, sklearn-pandas

The following is my code before I do hyperparameter tuning. I spilt my data into test and train using restrain split :

```
class_label=repair['PART_NO']
x=repair.drop('PART_NO',1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=cross_validation.train_test_split(x,class_label, train_size = 0.80)

def modelfit(alg, X_train, y_train ,useTrainCV=True, cv_folds=5,early_stopping_rounds=50):

if useTrainCV:
    xgb_param = alg.get_xgb_params()
    xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
    extra = {'num_class': 2182}
    xgb_param.update(extra)
    cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, 
                      xgtrain, 
                      num_boost_round=alg.get_params()['n_estimators'], 
                      nfold=cv_folds,
                      stratified=True,
                      metrics={'merror'},
                      early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
                      seed=0,
                      callbacks=[xgb.callback.print_evaluation(show_stdv=False)]),
    print cvresult
    alg.set_params(n_estimators=cvresult.shape[0])


#Fit the algorithm on the data
alg.fit(X_train, y_train,eval_metric='merror')
    
#Predict training set:
dtrain_predictions = alg.predict(X_test)
dtrain_predprob = alg.predict_proba(X_test)
    
#Print model report:
print "\nModel Report"
print "Accuracy : %.4g" % metrics.accuracy_score( dtrain_predictions,y_test)
print "Merror Score (Train): %f" % metrics.merror_score( dtrain_predprob,y_test)
                
feat_imp = pd.Series(alg.booster().get_fscore()).sort_values(ascending=False)
feat_imp.plot(kind='bar', title='Feature Importances')
plt.ylabel('Feature Importance Score')
```

After this I am trying to choose all predictors except the target and get the number of estimators as below:

```
xgb1 = XGBClassifier(
    learning_rate=0.1,
    n_estimators=280,
    max_depth=5,
    min_child_weight=1,
    gamma=0,
    subsample=0.8, 
    colsample_bytree=0.8,
    objective='multi:softprob',
    nthread=4,
    scale_pos_weight=1,
    seed=27
)
modelfit(xgb1, X_train, y_train)
```

However when doing this I get the following error even though I have mentioned the num_class in my xgb_params and my y_train is of type int.
Please suggest what to do? The exact error is as below:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 12  scale_pos_weight=1,
> 13  seed=27)
> ---> 14 modelfit(xgb1, X_train, y_train)
>
> in modelfit(alg, X_train, y_train,
> useTrainCV, cv_folds, early_stopping_rounds)
> 14                           early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
> 15                           seed=0,
> ---> 16                           callbacks=[xgb.callback.print_evaluation(show_stdv=False)]),
> 17         print cvresult
> 18         alg.set_params(n_estimators=cvresult.shape[0])
>
> /Users/sayontimondal/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.pyc
> in cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, nfold, stratified, folds,
> metrics, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, fpreproc,
> as_pandas, verbose_eval, show_stdv, seed, callbacks, shuffle)
> 404                            evaluation_result_list=None))
> 405         for fold in cvfolds:
> --> 406             fold.update(i, obj)
> 407         res = aggcv([f.eval(i, feval) for f in cvfolds])
> 408
>
> /Users/sayontimondal/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.pyc
> in update(self, iteration, fobj)
> 216     def update(self, iteration, fobj):
> 217         """"Update the boosters for one iteration"""
> --> 218         self.bst.update(self.dtrain, iteration, fobj)
> 219
> 220     def eval(self, iteration, feval):
>
> /Users/sayontimondal/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.pyc
> in update(self, dtrain, iteration, fobj)
> 892         if fobj is None:
> 893             _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterUpdateOneIter(self.handle, ctypes.c_int(iteration),
> --> 894                                                     dtrain.handle))
> 895         else:
> 896             pred = self.predict(dtrain)
>
> /Users/sayontimondal/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.pyc
> in _check_call(ret)
> 128     """
> 129     if ret != 0:
> --> 130         raise XGBoostError(_LIB.XGBGetLastError())
> 131
> 132
>
> XGBoostError: [13:34:08] src/objective/multiclass_obj.cc:78: Check
> failed: label_error >= 0 && label_error < nclass SoftmaxMultiClassObj:
> label must be in [0, num_class), num_class=2182 but found 2182 in
> label.
>
> Stack trace returned 7 entries: [bt] (0) 0   libxgboost.dylib
> 0x000000010d0684a0 dmlc::StackTrace() + 288 [bt] (1) 1
> libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000010d06823f
> dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 47 [bt] (2) 2
> libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000010d0dcf9a
> xgboost::obj::SoftmaxMultiClassObj::GetGradient(xgboost::HostDeviceVector*,
> xgboost::MetaInfo const&, int,
> xgboost::HostDeviceVectorxgboost::detail::GradientPairInternal<float
>
> > *) + 2218 [bt] (3) 3   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000010d0645f9 xgboost::LearnerImpl::UpdateOneIter(int,
> > xgboost::DMatrix*) + 1017 [bt] (4) 4   libxgboost.dylib
> > 0x000000010d07ef07 XGBoosterUpdateOneIter + 87 [bt] (5) 5   _ctypes.so
> > 0x0000000103528677 ffi_call_unix64 + 79 [bt] (6) 6   ???
> > 0x00007ffeefbfa980 0x0 + 140732920736128

And searching for it on google shows me no results.

Comment: `label must be in [0, num_class), num_class=2182 but found 2182 in label`. This should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your labels starting from 0 to the total of classes - 1.
For example- If you have class labels as (1,2,3,4,5). In order to feed it to a multi:softprob objective you need to convert it to (0,1,2,3,4)  classes.
It may be done by using **y.replace({1:0, 2:1, 3:2, 4:3, 5:4}, inplace = True)**

Answer (score -1):

Use NumClass instead of num_class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).